# Is Baron really game changing?

Tags: league-of-legends

So I recently played a normal game, and the kill count was 18-4 at about thirty minutes. We pushed to the inhib turrets in all three lanes, but we weren't aware of them doing Baron. They proceeded to win the game after acing us.

Comment: I honestly am not sure exactly what you are asking. Your title is very broad and that is generally okay if the body of the question is used to narrow down the scope of what you are asking. But there isn't a single question in the body of the question. Are you asking what stats Baron gives? I think you will get better answers if you try to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Considering the stats given, it's can certainly change the fight in their favor. But this all depends on team composition, and the fight itself. When the enemy team takes baron, just be prepared to turtle until it runs out. When that happens, the effectiveness is certainly reduced.

Answer (score 2):

not only is baron game changing even dragon can be game changing.

Baron gives everyone on your team 300 gold, that's roughly worth a kill to everyone so add 5 kills to the score plus the baron buff gives everyone a serious advantage in a teamfight so in most cases you need to defend until their buff wears off.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it definitely can be a game changer as killing the Baron awards the team with a buff that gives the wearer 40 attack damage, 40 ability power, 3% of their maximum health as hp/5 and 1% of their maximum mana as mp/5. They are given a decent advantage over you and if they had been taking towers and killing minions/jungling they might have kept up with you in gold upkeep enough to help. As well as Acing you which puts them in a position to fast push into your base with minimal resistance. A lot more info is needed for a better answer then kill count I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Baron is in fact game changing. In your case afer they got baron Im assuming it was late game so if you do get aced there is a good possiblity they will win.  However, since they only have 4 kills I'm curious  if they had any towers at all.  ALso your team could be ahead by kills but you might not have any cs or dragons so all those objectives come in handy.